# WP add functionality to reorder front page sections

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am building a theme and want to add the fuclnctionality to let the user reorder the front page sections. For example, if the normal order is "About", "Services", "Portfolio", and contact, but the user wants to swap the services and about sections, how do you add that into the theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is about nonadmin (anonymus users). You can use some kind of drag and drop js library to move the blocks, for example [Sortable](http://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/). After user reorder sections you have to store their position in localstorage or cookie, to keep their positions till next visit.

If this features is need by someone who has admin access you may use Gutenberg plugin or any other WordPress page builders almost all of them can reorder sections.

Comment: Ah okay. What if you wanted it in the customizer or on a custom admin page? Almost like the Hestia theme.

Comment: It can be done through Customizer you have to add custom options by useing its API https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/customizer-objects/. Basicaly you need to create position options for each section. Or if you prefer nocode solutions, you can try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/customizely/

As i've already said you may use Guttenberg plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/gutenberg/ it is in WordPress core or some other page builders Elementor, Divi or Wpbakery.

Comment: That is a cool API. I'm going to look into that. I prefer the coding option lol Is it possible to have the reordering on an admin page in the dashboard so the user doesn't have to go to the customizer?

Comment: Yes it is. You can create custom admin page (basicaly you have to create plugin wich creates admin page). More details here https://themes.artbees.net/blog/wordpress-custom-admin-pages/ Then add some options on this page, there is special API for this https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API

Comment: On the frontend of your site you can get options values using this function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/

Comment: So I could create custom fields on the page for each homepage section, but then how do you tell it the order? Do you have the user give each a number and sort them on the front end?

Comment: You've asked about separate admin page. There is also a way to do it with custom fields. Check ACF plugin https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ (it is free) it has addon (paid) https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/ with it you can create groups of custom fileds (sections) and connect them to the page of your choice. Then in your theme temeplate you can get this section in order you set https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/. It is the most painless solution for custom field management.

Comment: Advanced custom fields is a great feature, but do you have an example for how do do it with the settings api and displaying it in the order that is provided by the user?

Comment: So if I make options on the admin page, and use get option to retreive them, how do you link those option choices to the sections? Would each section have to be a different file and save each in a variable?

Comment: I dont know how do you store sections (separate fields on page or different pages/posts). You may try to create an multidemensional array with sort_order and section content in it and sort it with array_multisort function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: Is it possible to grab the setting from the admin page and use a filter to rearrange the sections? If I used that function you mentioned, how would you number the sections to sort them?

Comment: In admin options set sections sort order form zero (top section) to whatever number you need. See Example 3 on the https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php instead of volume you will have sort order instead of edition your section html. But I still suggest you, using ACF custom fields connected to the page it is much easier and better looking approach.